# Can I run/debug Windows Store App on the Mobile Device?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, remote-debugging

I've created my project (DLL and App) as the Windows Store App (XAML) and can run/debug it on the Windows 8 desktop using MS Dev Studio 2012. The project is to port some networking toolkit and thus the UI is not important, all I need is ability to print some data on the screen.
At the moment I cannot run the application on the mobile device (I have Lumia 920). It fails to deploy saying "Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named ...". 
Is it possible in general to run the Windows Store Apps on the Lumia? What needs to be done?

Thanks,
Rafi

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 apps are not compatible with Windows Phone 8. So it's impossible to deploy your Windows 8 app on your Lumia 920.